# Hey! Do you know how to dynamically change the layout in Nuxt without store?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

There is my default layout.
I want to change visibility on my header, when my modal is open, but I don't know how to change it dynamically. Any ideas?

// default.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <header class="default-header">
      <router-link class="logo" to="/"></router-link>

      <div class="button-group">
        <router-link to="/login" class="btn">Log in</router-link>
        <router-link to="/register" class="btn">Sign up</router-link>
      </div>
    </header>

    <nuxt />
  </div>
</template>
```

//index.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div @click="openModal">Open Modal</div>
    <modal-popup v-model="showModal"></modal-popup>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ModalPopup from "~/components/ModalPopup";
export default {
  name: "Login",
  components: {
    ModalPopup
  },
  data() {
    return {
      showModal: false;
    }
  },
  methods() {
    openModal() {
      this.showModal = true;
    },
    closeModal() {
      this.showModal = false;
    },
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: why without store?

Comment: I think that is not good to include store just for this task. I don't use it in my project

Answer (score 0):

To do it without a store you can create an EventBus to trigger events which you can listen to. An eventbus provides communication between vue components.

You can create an eventbus js file.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
const EventBus = new Vue();

export default EventBus;
```

Then in your components you can import it

```
import EventBus from '/eventbus'
```

In the index.vue component in your openModal() function you can change it to trigger the open modal event like this

```
openModal() {
     EventBus.$emit('modal-opened', true);
     this.showModal = true;
}
```

then in your default.vue component you can add a listener in the mounted function

```
mounted() {
    EventBus.$on(‘modal-open’, function (payLoad) {
      // Change header visibility here
    });
}
```

Extra Note

If you don't want to import the Eventbus all the time you can import Eventbus in your app.js and just before your `new Vue()` you can add bus to the vue properties so your file will look something like this

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import EventBus from '/eventbus'

Object.defineProperties(
   Vue.prototype,
   {
      $bus: {
          get() => { return EventBus; }
      }
   }
)

new Vue({})
```

Then you can access the bus in your components like this

```
this.$bus.$emit('modal-open', true);
```

and

```
this.$bus.$on('modal-open', function(payload) {

})
```

Hope that helps